# Images not found because @@pluginfile@@ getting bad url

Tags: moodle

I have the next problem with @@pluginfile@@ urls.

When I upload a Image to moodle repository file management and I use plugin file to load any image, it gives me this url:

```
From:

    src="@@pluginfile@@/ConoceADashAndDotWEB.png"

Transform into:

    src="pluginfile.php/132/mod_forum/post/7/ConoceADashAndDotWEB.png"
```

But it should transform url into:

```
src="pluginfile.php/72/mod_forum/post/7/ConoceADashAndDotWEB.png"
```

As consequence, I can't see images because they are not found. I really don't understand how @@pluginfile@@ works.

Answer (score 1):

When Moodle displays the text which includes @@pluginfile@@ somewhere inside, it should call the function file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls(), passing in the details of the contextid, component, file area and itemid that should be used to generate the full URL.

I would be surprised if the forum module was passing in the wrong details for this (as it has been working in a lot of sites for several years now).

Where are you seeing this output (in the forum, or in your own plugin)?
Why do you believe that the contextid should be 72 instead of 132?
Do you have any idea where the (incorrect) 132 is coming from?

Comment: This happens when I create a post and I upload an image. In the preview of the post before publish  I can see the url of the image good (with 72) but when I get the text from database (which saved the image's url as "@@pluginfile@@/ConoceADashAndDotWEB.png") and I print that, it transforms the url to the second one (with 132). I'll try looking for that method.